# Inno setup window title is corrupted (botva2.dll)

Tags: inno-setup

I created multi-language setup + VCL-styles, and I had a problem with standard progressbar(progressgauge) - it flickers and looks ugly overall. So I used botva2.dll with 2 png's and now it looks perfect - but the problem now is: after ImgLoad call

```
function ImgLoad(Wnd :HWND; FileName :PAnsiChar; Left, Top, Width, Height :integer;     Stretch, IsBkg :boolean) :Longint; external 'ImgLoad@{tmp}\botva2.dll stdcall delayload';
```

wizardform title is corruprted, and as far as I understand its because botva2 is not unicode and it subclasses a wnd (Wizardform in my case), and as a result window title is corrupted in current language isnt a system language.
I tried creating TPanel and feeding botva a panel handle - its not working, unfortunately.
I tried adding doublebuffer to original progressgauge and making somehow look good - with no result.
Any ideas or workarounds?

PS. Summoning @TLama...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help here because botva2 is closed source (as far I know). I don't even know what that library is for. But if it's ANSI, then you'll surely lose your Unicode form caption. If you are using it because of lack of missing PNG file support in Inno Setup, then we would better file a feature request and drop botva2 from your project.

Comment: Creating Form inside WizardForm and make botva2 working with it works fine, rendering with own gdi+ library works fine, I with we could file few feature requests to Inno.

Comment: PNG support for Inno would be a great feature.